# Upload file to a webservice url

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload, webforms

I used these below codes for sending file to a soap webservice method:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://DomainName.com/WebService.asmx?op=SaveVideoHere");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

byte[] fileData = null;
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
{
  fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
}
request.ContentLength = fileData.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
stream.Dispose();
reader.Dispose();
```

In Webservice :

```
[WebMethod]
public void SaveVideoHere() 
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] != null)
    {
        this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        this.Context.Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].FileName);
        return;
    }
}
```

But file doesn't send and there are this error

> `Additional information: The remote server returned an error:
>   (500) Internal Server Error.`

What I must be do?

Comment: Status code 500 means something is wrong in your webservice method. cross check your webservice code

Comment: that's what i meant. Your called webservice method have some logical issues and couldn't complete the execution of the incoming request. so it return status code 500. so if you the author of http://DomainName.com/WebService.asmx, then verify it whether works properly or not

Comment: @Ritz,Thank you,it solved by your guidance.in my webservice method `if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] != null)` is wrong,and must be use `if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count != 0)` replace that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer following link for more details.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318425/how-to-send-and-receive-binary-documents-by-using-an-asp.net-web-service-and-visual-c-.net

and set read and write permission on folder.

Comment: This link does not exist anymore :(

Comment: I think, The following links will help you. - 
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-file-using-Web-Service-ASMX-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my webservice I used this below codes.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count != 0)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string ServerPath = Server.MapPath("/storage/");
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].SaveAs(ServerPath + HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].FileName);
        this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        this.Context.Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].FileName);
        return;
    }
}
```

I tested it with postman and it's ok.I mean my webservice take file and save the file in path.

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(WebServiceOfServer);
 request.Method = "POST";
 //request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 request.KeepAlive = true;
 request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
 var boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
 request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

 byte[] fileData = null;
 using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
            {
                fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
            }
            request.ContentLength = fileData.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Dispose();
            reader.Dispose();
```

but when I send file with my webform project,in side of my webservice just the `ContentLength` of file exists,and cannot receive file. `Request.Files.Count` is 0.
What is wrong in my webform project codes?